# Capture remainder of URL with DoneJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, donejs

Basically, what I'm aiming to do is capture the rest of a url in a route and store it into the ViewModel.

In AngularJS, you can do this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/foo/:page*', { ... });
```

...and when you access `/foo/bar/baz`, for example, `$routeParams.page` is `'bar/baz'`.

So I attempted something similar in DoneJS, with the following line in the `app.js`:

```
route('/foo/:page*', { page: 'home' });
```

Which, really, should work, right?

**Nope.** When you reload, the Nodejs console is flooded with:

```
WARN: can/view/stache/mustache_core.js: Unable to find key or helper "page".
```

Moreover, an asterisk flickers on and off at the end of the URL, the contents of "page" in the ViewModel changes rapidly between `'home'` and `undefined`, and the browser locks up (tried with Chrome and Firefox) after a few seconds.

I have tired removing the `*` from the route, but this causes `/foo/bar/baz` to not match while `/foo/bar` does.

**How can I capture the remainder of the URL into the ViewModel?**